# Theano: using dot "T" at the end of a dot product where number of dimensions is greater than one

Tags: python, theano

I was going through an LSTM code by Jonathan Raiman and I encountered this line of code in "Layer" class

```
if x.ndim > 1:
    return  T.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(self.linear_matrix,x.T)  + self.bias_matrix[:,None]).T
```

`T` is `"import theano.tensor as T"`

x is a symbolic variable

what does x.T do?
what does that (return statement).T do??

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x.T` is the transpose of the matrix `x`.

`.T` is a notation that applies transpose to numpy matrices, which is the same as `numpy.transpose(x)`. It should not be confused with the name `T` from  `import theano.tensor as T`

And

> (return statement).T

*returns* the transpose of the output of the sigmoid function applied on the parameter: `T.dot(self.linear_matrix,x.T)  + self.bias_matrix[:,None]`